# Would it work efficiently if I use MS access as a front end and MySQL as a back end?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, frontend, backend

I'm using elements such as Macros,SQL, Lookups, Dlookups, etc... Would these objects operate normally if I used the proposed structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Yes. Use the official ODBC driver for data access.